# Is there a way to add paths to 3rd Party assemblies for proper directory harvesting by heat?

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5

We are trying to introduce more automation into the generation of our installation using heat.  Our build outputs artifacts in a directory that I would like to harvest using heat.  Since we do not output 3rd party assemblies into the artifacts directory we receive a HEAT5151 warning (Could not harvest data from a file that was expected to be an assembly....)  Is there a way to reference a path to the 3rd party libraries for heat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution would be to output the third-parties to the same directory to let heat resolve the references. Otherwise, you're facing the problem outlined [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3078541&group_id=105970&atid=642714). This issue was moved to be fixed in v4.0 as you can see.

Comment: I guess it is what it is until a valid fix is released.Thanks!

Comment: By now the WiX issue tracker has been moved to github: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/2878